# How does Joomla 4 decide a component is legacy?

Tags: component, joomla-4.x

What determines whether Joomla 4 treats something as a legacy component?

Answer (score 3):

Any component that is an instance of `Joomla\CMS\Extension\LegacyComponent`. This includes:

1. J3 style components that do not have `services/provider.php` file returning a service provider.
2. J4 components that do not provide an implementation of `Joomla\CMS\Extension\ComponentInterface`.
3. J4 components that provide an instance of `Joomla\CMS\Extension\LegacyComponent` (which does implement `Joomla\CMS\Extension\ComponentInterface`).